# Magento 2 and M2Epro Ebay Listing Inventory Synchronisation Issue

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, m2epro

I am facing problem between Magento 2 and M2Epro Ebay Listing Inventory Synchronisation. Inventory in not sync between M2epro ebay listing.

I have checked synchronisation settings and those shows correct. But still inventory is not correct on M2Epro Ebay Listing.

Now I am writing a code as per [this tutorial](https://docs.m2epro.com/display/BestPracticeMagento2/Suitable+Articles+from+the+Best+Practice+for+Magento+v1.x#SuitableArticlesfromtheBestPracticeforMagentov1.x-ProgrammaticPossibilitiestoworkwithExtension) to observe product and update inventory.

Github Location for M2Epro - https://github.com/m2epro/magento2-extension

But I am getting error that

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'Ess\M2ePro\Model\PublicServices\Product\ObjectChange' not found
```

Below is my code -

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$modelFactory = $objectManager->create('\Ess\M2ePro\Model\Factory');
$model = $modelFactory->create('PublicServices\Product\ObjectChange');
$model->observeProduct($id);
```

Can anyone help me to fix this.

Is there any other way to fix inventory synchronisation issue ?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/CodistoConnect/CodistoConnect-Magento2 uses mview to avoid needing to do manual coding to keep inventories in sync

also - Magento has released their own Amazon integration https://magento.com/news-room/press-releases/magento-gives-merchants-access-to-amazon-marketplace

Comment: I am looking for to fix my code .. Not for buy another one extension.